# Dynamic CSS Sprite animation size

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic application where one of the templates contains sprite animation. The animation works fine except that the size is fixed for any device I use. Here's the code I use:

**CSS**

```
#animation_boy {
width: 558px;
height: 1536px;
background-image: url("../img/boy_sprite.png");
-webkit-animation: play 1.2s steps(7) infinite;
animation: play 1.1s steps(7) infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px
  }
  to {
    background-position: -3906px
  }
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px
  }
  to {
    background-position: -3906px
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="animation_boy"></div>
```

I want to make the size depend on the screen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try a relative unit like percentage `%` or viewport like `-50vh` instead of fixed pixel value.

Comment: I tried that, but the image disappears...

Comment: tinker the value until its right...... use live inspector to save time but really a relative unit is the way to go.

Comment: I tried with multiple values, it just disappears. You could try it to verify.

Comment: create a jsFiddle or send live link so I could inspect it properly, thanks